# Default landing page without language suffix

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, redirect, multilingual, multi-sites

I have a multilanguage Joomla website.

How can I configure my site so that when someone types any url, it will always bring them to: www.mysite.com ?

Currently, a suffix is always added to my site name. Thats okay for when languages are chosen, but I just don't want that for my default landing page.

I tried the following modification in htaccess. I think it's just looping back to my website with the suffix.

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Language Filter plugin, enable the **Remove URL Language Code**.

This setting will remove the language url code from the urls for the default content language of your website.

Comment: Yes, that removes language url code from all sites by default language. Actually i want to remove url code only from landing page.

Comment: @Navitua sorry, from your htaccess code, I thought you wanted to redirect all pages of default language and it was not very clear what you meant with default landing page. So you have a landing page which is will be the same for all languages, or what? Keep in mind that Joomla will keep redirecting pages to meet the appropriate language url code.